# What is a series of tokens? (from an article)

Tags: php, cookies

I just read **[this](http://jaspan.com/improved_persistent_login_cookie_best_practice)** article and I pretty much got it, although there is still something I'm not quite sure about... in the `Solution` part, the writer talks about a `series of tokens`.
Did he mean a unique ID for a username that never changes? would the normal user id stored in the database be fine for this use? That 'normal' user id will most likely be known to the user, so I'm not sure if this is supposed to be kept secure or not...
And, what is a good way to generate a token 'from a large space' as recommended in the article?

Comment: Just a wild guess.. Are you working on a login / user system and do you want to know how to make it secure?

Comment: Yes this is for a login system. I already know how to make it secure, now I'm working on the 'Remember me' part, which I also thrive to make secure and prevent as much hijacks as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One naive way to generate the series of tokens is to iterate a hash:

T_0: username + hash(username)
T_1: username + hash(T_0)
T_2: username + hash(T_1)
...

The downside to this approach is a stolen cookie gives away future access. A better way to generate the series of tokens is to use a [CTR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation#Counter_.28CTR.29)-style approach:

R = rand()
T_0: username + hash(R)
T_1: username + hash(R+1)
T_2: username + hash(R+2)
...

If the hash is strong enough (SHA-256, for example), and the random number really is selected *randomly* from a large enough pool (reading a dozen bytes from `/dev/urandom` for an easy source..) then knowledge of any one cookie couldn't be used to figure out future cookies -- without going through the web service, that is.

Comment: The problem is that the `series of tokens` is supposed to be unique, and to never change...

Comment: Actually, after reading it again, the token always changes to a new one, and all of those tokens have a series id... so in the database it would come out like this : `username | seriesId | token` where the `seriesId` is unique to each username. Correct me if I'm wrong?

Comment: Thanks. The writer also wrote `a login cookie is issued in addition to the standard session management cookie.` and that the `standard session management cookie.` should be a session cookie. What exactly is that `standard session management cookie.`? (I know what a session cookie is.)

Comment: The `standard session management cookie` is one of the `series of tokens` in this case -- it's the cookie that provides password-less reuse of the site.

Comment: I just found this in the original article : [link](http://fishbowl.pastiche.org/2004/01/19/persistent_login_cookie_best_practice) `Standard session-management handles the credentials for the life of the session, so the newly assigned cookie will not be checked until the next session (at which point it, too, will be invalidated after use).` So basically the value of this cookie is the time that the user should be logged in right? (eg. xxx seconds) Although, as a `session cookie` is expires when the browser is closed and cannot be accessed no more, so how long will the user stay logged in?

Comment: The above also means I will have to store the last time that a user logged in, right? (and then calculate if it's past the cookie's expiration time)

Comment: Hrm. I think you're right but that sounds entirely too complicated. :/

Comment: Exactly. I'm pretty confused about it. Thanks anyways I will open a new question!

Answer (score 2):

Read the article:

> The login cookie contains the user's username and a random number (the "token" from here on)

So a "series of tokens" is "a series of randomly generated numbers."

Comment: a token can also contain other chars besides numbers

Comment: How long, how many? After all a new token is generated for a username each time he logs in, and that series cannot be changed... I'm wondering if really that secure to just guess the number of chars...

Comment: The length of the token depends on how the application is build

Answer (score 2):

A token is a string containing random chars and/or number. `a series of tokens` is a collection of random chars / numbers

UPDATE:
To make a secure Remember Me function on your website, the best way you do that is:

- Place the website behind SSL, if it drops your performance, place only the sensitive parts behind SSL.
- When a user clicks "Remember Me", create 2 COOKIES. 1 regular session cookie and 1 with a unique string (a token)
- Always verify if both cookies are available, if a session get's hijacked, the hacker only has the session cookie.